# How can I output the value of a superTable field within a loop?

Tags: templating, plugin-supertable

I have a `superTable` field that I am trying to re-populate on my front-end form.

Everything is working great, I am able to populate a drop-down, but can't seem to find the magic numbers to re-populate a textfield.

```
<label>{{ field.name }}</label>
<input type="text" name="fields[myField][fields][{{ field.handle }}]" class="form-control" value="{{ entry.myField[0].??? }}">
```

This works well:

```
fields[myField][fields][{{ field.handle }}]
```

But, whatever I enter after that `.` Example:

```
value="{{ entry.myField[0].field.handle }}"
```

I get the error that the model "field doesn't exist". If could make `field.handle` just be "myField" everything would be great. I can hard-code the field name and it works great. But, I need to be able to access the values within a loop.

Thank you for any suggestions!

**EDIT**

```
value="{{ entry.myField[0].field.handle }}"
```

Is a plainTex field. This is the output I am trying to accomplish.

```
<input type="text" name="fields[myField][fields][{{ field.handle }}]" value="{{ entry.myField[0].field.handle }}">
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct markup is:

```
{{ block[field.handle] }}
```

The final looks like this:

```
<input type="text" name="fields[myField][fields][{{ field.handle }}]" value="{{ block[field.handle] }}">
```

Comment: Can you post this including the for-loop expression that sets `block`. The code doesn’t make a whole lot of sense without.

Comment: Same issue with your question btw, what is `fields` or `field`?